# Does this sequence have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've seen this sequence come up as a solution to a couple of my favorite puzzles, but I've never heard a name for it. It's self similar in a very particular way. If I'm not mistaken, it also happens to denote the digit which flips at each step of a Gray code.

```
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 7
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 8
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 7
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5
1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 9
...
```

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the link in the comment shows this is called the "ruler function" in English. This is so because rulers in non-metric systems tend to subdivide distances into halves: a large mark at each inch, a somewhat smaller mark at half-inches, an even smaller mark at quarter-inches and so forth. If this is done to a considerable depth, the sizes of successive marks vary somewhat like the values of the ruler function (which assigns to each $i\neq0$ the exponent of the largest power of $2$ that divides it, which is also called its $2$-adic valuation), although this would in fact require extra-large marks at double inches etc. which actual rulers don't have.

The ruler function is discussed (as so many other things) in [Concrete Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics), where its first use (in section 4.4) is that the multiplicity of $2$ as prime factor of $n!$ equals the sum of the values of the ruler function at arguments from $1$ up to $n$.